# How do you describe something that develops rapidly, is packed with events?

Tags: word-request

Yes, I consulted a thesaurus, no help (or I couldn't use it properly). I need an adjective that describes a process that develops rapidly and is full of events (regardless of whether they are good or bad) as opposed to something stagnant, not changing. For example, '[word] political life of [a country]'. 'Turbulent' has negative connotations, I need something neutral or, maybe, slightly sarcastic. I also know the word 'eventful'. It doesn't fit either, in my view.

Comment: [***volatile***](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/volatile) synonyms.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I haven't found a single word that suits my needs

Comment: Please explain why ***volatile*** and ***fluid***, for example, don't suit your needs.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica "Liable to change rapidly and unpredictably, especially for the worse" Whereas I need a word that describes something that does changes rapidly (not just "liable") and is packed with events and developments

Comment: I wouldn't take too much notice of that "especially for the worse", even for ***volatile***. It's not so much part of the meaning of the *word* - just that pragmatically speaking, unstable rapidly-changing environments are *usually* "problematic" (evolution being the archetypal context to illustrate the fact that "random change" is more likely to be bad than good). But personally I'd very specifically say that using ***fluid*** rather than ***volatile*** completely does away with that element anyway.

Comment: *change 7 more to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the word "*unstable*", which doesn't necessarily suggest that it changes *quickly*, but it does mean something could change *at any time*.

Otherwise, I can't think of a single, widely-used adjective to describe something that changes rapidly. Those are two different qualities. You might as well ask for a single adjective that describes something that moves and is red.

I would suggest you use a *hyphenated compound* of two words instead. Here are some possibilities:

- Rapidly-evolving
- Ever-changing
- Constantly-developing
- Fast-moving

Any of the above could potentially be mixed-and-matched, although these sound the most idiomatic to my ears.

There is also the expression "*in a state of flux*" which pretty much means unstable, but it wouldn't insert into your sentence without some re-writing.

Comment: Perhaps also action-packed?